Is it possible to use a Chromebook as a Raspberry Pi 5 screen?
I'm planning on buying an 8GB Pi 5 and was wondering if there was any way to connect the Pi 5 to a Chromebook for use as a monitor. I've tried looking for info online but couldn't find much. Thanks!

yes ... research Linux remote desktop

If part of the context here is that you don't have a screen and keyboard to do the initial setup of the Pi, etc., then no, connecting it to a chromebook is not a feasible solution and I highly recommend you beg borrow or steal a screen and keyboard for at least a few hours.
If you mean you want to physically connect them via a USB cable or something, this is really a question about your chromebook we cannot answer, but it is almost certainly no, which is generally the answer to, "Can I physically plug another computer into my laptop to use its screen?".
Beyond that (ie., connection via network) the usual way to do this is via some form of remote desktop software.  This will run inside Chrome OS on the chromebook and provide a window presenting the Pi GUI desktop or a GUI application running on it.  The most popular mechanism for this is probably VNC; this is a generic category of software like "web browser", there are a few major implementations and not all of them are usable from the Pi side.
We currently have ~400 VNC oriented questions here, so I suggest you look through these and do some research of your own; if you find something you can't figure out or find an existing answer to then feel free to ask a specific question about that.
There are a couple of other options around:

It's possible for at least some chromebooks to use X forwarding.  A minor issue with this is that the current version of RaspiOS does not use the X server anymore by default, but it can be configured to do so.

NoMachine is freeware which has an Android client that can be installed on Chrome OS (but YMMV).


WRT to bandwidth, if you have trouble over wifi and both the chromebook and the Pi have an ethernet jack free, you can connect them that way.
